# Abstract class and IModelBinder, how to get a correct ValidationState?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-2.2, imodelbinder

**Context**:

I have an angular App which send complex Data to my .net Core API. Data sent could be an Image (ImageDto) or a couple of Images (StackImageDto), and Title & Tags. We send Data  using multi-part HTML form, It means the Data is not JSON formatted.

**Bug**:

There is currently a bug in .Net Core 2.2 with *BindModelAsync*:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6616

**Similar issues**:

I try to follow what people suggested but I didnt succeed to make it work correctly:

- https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4703
- http://qaru.site/questions/1630337/mvc-6-custom-model-binder-with-dependency-injection
- [Model binder for abstract class in asp.net core mvc 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48214501/model-binder-for-abstract-class-in-asp-net-core-mvc-2)

**Code**:

As I need to make the API works, I use a different way to set my abstract class DTO used in the controller.

Here is the DTO classes, *MediaDto*:

```
[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(AbstractModelBinder))]
public abstract class MediaDto
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public TagDto[] Tags { get; set; } = new TagDto[] { };
    public ChallengeDetailsDto[] Challenges { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Discriminator { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset? CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    //public Guid CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? EditedAt { get; set; }
    public string EditedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? DeletedAt { get; set; }
    public string DeletedBy { get; set; }
}
```

*ImageDto*:

```
[Serializable]
public class ImageDto : MediaDto
{
    public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public ImageDto()
    {
        Discriminator = ImageDtoDiscriminator;
    }
}
```

*StackImageDto*:

```
[Serializable]
public class StackImageDto : MediaDto
{
    [Required]
    [EnumDataType(typeof(StackImageType))]
    public StackImageType Type { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public IEnumerable<StackFileDto> StackFiles { get; set; }

    public StackImageDto()
    {
        Discriminator = StackImageDtoDiscriminator;
    }
}
```

*StackFileDto*

```
[Serializable]
public class StackFileDto
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
}
```

*MediaLibraryConverter* convert the Json to my instance of MediaDto:

```
public class MediaLibraryConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(MediaDto).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        MediaDto result = null;

        var jsonChallange = JObject.Load(reader);
        var discriminator = jsonChallange.Properties().First(p => p.Name == "discriminator").Value.ToString();

        if (discriminator.Equals(nameof(ImageDto), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            result = (ImageDto)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonChallange.ToString(), typeof(ImageDto));
        }
        else if (discriminator.Equals(nameof(StackImageDto), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            result = (StackImageDto)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonChallange.ToString(), typeof(StackImageDto));
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ApiException($"{nameof(MediaDto)} discriminator is not set properly.", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

*AbstractModelBinder* does the context binding, as I get the data using [FromForm] attribute in the action of the controller:

```
public class AbstractModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));

        // Fetch the value of the argument by name and set it to the model state
        string fieldName = bindingContext.FieldName;

        try
        {
            var data = ExtractDataFromContext(bindingContext)[0];
            var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(fieldName, new ValueProviderResult(jsonData));

            var discriminator = JObject.Parse(jsonData)
                .Properties()
                .First(p => p.Name == "discriminator")
                .Value
                .ToString();

            // Deserialize the provided value and set the binding result
            if (discriminator.Equals(nameof(ImageDto), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                object o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ImageDto>(jsonData, new MediaLibraryConverter());
                o = BindFormFiles(o, bindingContext);
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(o);
            }
            else if (discriminator.Equals(nameof(StackImageDto), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                object o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StackImageDto>(jsonData, new MediaLibraryConverter());
                o = BindFormFiles(o, bindingContext);
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(o);
            }
        }
        catch (JsonException e)
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

*BindFormFiles* is a recursive function helping to bind json and IFormFile getting from HttpContext to an Instance of MediaDto

```
    private object BindFormFiles(object tmp, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, string fieldName = null)
    {
        if (tmp == null)
        {
            return tmp;
        }

        var type = tmp.GetType();
        if (type.IsPrimitive || typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            return tmp;
        }

        if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type) && !typeof(IEnumerable<IFormFile>).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            var array = (IList)tmp;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
            {
                array[i] = BindFormFiles(array[i], bindingContext, $"{fieldName}[{i}]");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var property in tmp.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                var name = property.Name;
                if (typeof(IFormFile).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
                {
                    var file = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.Files
                        .FirstOrDefault(f => string.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldName)
                            ? f.Name.Equals($"{property.Name}", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                            : f.Name.Equals($"{fieldName}.{property.Name}", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                        );
                    if (file != null)
                    {
                        property.SetValue(tmp, file);
                    }
                }
                else if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
                {
                    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(IEnumerable<IFormFile>))
                    {
                        var files = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.Files
                            .Where(f => string.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldName)
                                ? f.Name.Equals($"{property.Name}", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                : f.Name.Equals($"{fieldName}.{property.Name}", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                            );
                        if (files?.Any() == true)
                        {
                            property.SetValue(tmp, files);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        property.SetValue(
                            tmp,
                            BindFormFiles(
                                property.GetValue(tmp),
                                bindingContext,
                                string.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldName)
                                    ? property.Name
                                    : $"{fieldName}.{property.Name}"
                            )
                        );
                    }
                }
                else if (property.PropertyType.IsClass && !typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
                {
                    property.SetValue(
                        tmp,
                        BindFormFiles(
                            property.GetValue(tmp),
                            bindingContext,
                            property.Name
                        )
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        return tmp;
    }
```

*ExtractDataFromContext* is a recursive function extracting Data from HttpContext

```
    private List<Dictionary<string, object>> ExtractDataFromContext(ModelBindingContext bindingContext, string fieldName = null)
    {
        var i = 0;
        var propertyName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldName)
            ? string.Empty
            : $"{fieldName}[{i}]";
        var result = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

        while (bindingContext.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Form
            .Where(kv => string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName)
                ? true
                : kv.Key.StartsWith(propertyName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            )
            .DistinctBy(kv => kv.Key.Substring(0, propertyName.Length))
            .Any()
        )
        {
            var values = bindingContext.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Form
                .Where(kv => string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName)
                    ? true
                    : kv.Key.StartsWith($"{fieldName}[{i}]", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                )
                .ToDictionary(
                    kv => string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName)
                        ? kv.Key
                        : kv.Key.Replace($"{propertyName}.", string.Empty, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase),
                    kv => (object)kv.Value[0]
                );

            var subValues = values
                .Where(kv => kv.Key.Contains("]."))
                .GroupBy(kv => kv.Key.Substring(0, kv.Key.IndexOf("[")))
                .ToDictionary(
                    g => g.Key,
                    g => string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName)
                        ? (object)ExtractDataFromContext(bindingContext, $"{g.Key}")
                        : (object)ExtractDataFromContext(bindingContext, $"{propertyName}.{g.Key}")

                )
                .Concat(values
                    .Where(kv => kv.Key.Contains("]") && !kv.Key.Contains("]."))
                    .GroupBy(kv => kv.Key.Substring(0, kv.Key.IndexOf("[")))
                    .ToDictionary(
                        g => g.Key,
                        g => (object)g.Select(kv => kv.Value)
                    )
                );

            result.Add(values
                .Where(kv => !kv.Key.Contains("]"))
                .Concat(subValues)
                .ToList()
                .ToDictionary(
                    kv => kv.Key,
                    kv => kv.Value
                )
            );
            i++;
            propertyName = $"{fieldName}[{i}]";
        }
        return result;
    }
```

For people interested to know what the HttpContext.Request.Form contains:

*Files*:
[image]

*Keys*:
[image]

*ValidateModelStateAttribute* is an ActionFilterAttribute validating the current ModelState for all controller actions

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ValidateModelStateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the ModelState is not valid not because of errors but because the ValidationState is 'unvalidated'.

[image]

If I bypass the ActionFilter and go in the action of my controller, I can see the Dto correctly filled:
[image]

**Question**:

How can I say to *context.ModelState* that his *ValidationState* is valid?

Comment: Did you consider not having this abstraction at all? A little bit of duplication might not  hurt that much.

Comment: Also by the looks is not that polymorphic, at some point you use that discriminator to check the derived type.

Comment: Yes we considered it. But Currently we can't modify, mobile apps and Angular Website, we can only update the API. Every thing worked before. I can exclude the AttributeValidator too for MediaDto type only, but I would like to avoid to patch the error like this.

Comment: Try looking at the ValidateNever attribute.