# Model binder for abstract class reference within abstract class asp.net core mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I'm following along at [Model binder for abstract class in asp.net core mvc 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48214501/model-binder-for-abstract-class-in-asp-net-core-mvc-2), but my model doesn't bind the HostedControls in ConcreteControlHost (see below). If I change the type of HostedControls to ConcreteControlText[], it does bind. I'd like to keep it as AbstractControl[] so that I can host multiple types of control.

I know the abstract binder is working because MainModel.Controls binds.

While debugging the binding of ConcreteControlHost, binder._propertyBinders has an entry for HostedControls as follows:
`{[ModelMetadata (Property: 'ConcreteControlHost.HostedControls' Type: 'AbstractControl[]'), {Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ArrayModelBinder<MyProject.AbstractControl>}]}`
Following that property (Value.ElementBinder.Inner) eventually leads to AbstractModelBinder.

Breakpoints in AbstractModelBinder are not hit when binding the properties of ConcreteControlHost, but are when binding the properties of MainModel (as in, I get the hits for ConcreteControlHost, but not for ConcreteControlText).

This isn't related to [In an Editor Template call another Editor Template with the same Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811717/in-an-editor-template-call-another-editor-template-with-the-same-model) because it isn't the *same* model, and because everything renders correctly, it just doesn't bind. None of the ConcreteControlTexts referenced by HostedControls are referenced directly by MainModel.Controls.

```
public class MainModel {
   public AbstractControl[] Controls;
}

public abstract class AbstractControl {
   public string TypeName { get; set;}
}

public class ConcreteControlText: AbstractControl {
   public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteControlHost: AbstractControl {
   public AbstractControl[] HostedControls { get; set; }
}
```

Does anyone see what I need to change to allow model-binding to work on ConcreteControlHost.HostedControls?

Comment: Your `IModelBinderProvider` would be the first thing to debug. Are you creating your `IModelBinder` for the correct types? You should post the source for both, and how you are configuring them on startup.

Comment: Looks like ArrayModelBinder will silently skip an array that is not null. Is there any chance that ConcreteControlHost will create an array before binding has completed? https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/Binders/ArrayModelBinder.cs

Answer (score 0):

Turns out in my actual code, HostedControls had `{ get; private set; }`. Removing the private modifier on the setter made it work.

Jeremy, thanks for looking into this.