# Abstract class model binding in asp.net core web api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, model-binding

I have been trying to figure out how to use custom model binding with .net Core 2 web api but have not been able to get it working.

I have been through some articles as below
http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2018/5/13/aspnet-core-model-binding-of-abstract-classes
[Asp net core rc2. Abstract class model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318029/asp-net-core-rc2-abstract-class-model-binding)

In my case, the **bindingContext.ModelName** is always empty. Can anybody explain why this could be?

Sample implementation below

Controller

```
        public IActionResult SomeAction([ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(BlahTypeModelBinder))][FromBody]TheBaseClass theBase)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

Models

```
public abstract class TheBaseClass
{
    public abstract int WhatType { get; }
}

public class A : TheBaseClass
{
    public override int WhatType { get { return 1; }  }
}

public class B : TheBaseClass
{
    public override int WhatType { get { return 2; } }
}
```

Provider

```
public class BhalTypeBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(TheBaseClass))
        {
            var assembly = typeof(TheBaseClass).Assembly;
            var abstractSearchClasses = assembly.GetExportedTypes()
                .Where(t => t.BaseType.Equals(typeof(TheBaseClass)))
                .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract)
                .ToList();

            var modelBuilderByType = new Dictionary<Type, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexTypeModelBinder>();

            foreach (var type in abstractSearchClasses)
            {
                var propertyBinders = new Dictionary<ModelMetadata, IModelBinder>();
                var metadata = context.MetadataProvider.GetMetadataForType(type);

                foreach (var property in metadata.Properties)
                {
                    propertyBinders.Add(property, context.CreateBinder(property));
                }

                modelBuilderByType.Add(type, new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexTypeModelBinder(propertyBinders));
            }

            return new BlahTypeModelBinder(modelBuilderByType, context.MetadataProvider);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Binder

```
public class BlahTypeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private readonly IModelMetadataProvider _metadataProvider;
    private readonly IDictionary<Type, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexTypeModelBinder> _binders;

    public BlahTypeModelBinder(IDictionary<Type, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexTypeModelBinder> binders, IModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider)
    {
        _metadataProvider = metadataProvider;
        _binders = binders;
    }

    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));

        var modelTypeValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(ModelNames.CreatePropertyModelName(bindingContext.ModelName, "WhatType"));
        if (modelTypeValue != null && modelTypeValue.FirstValue != null)
        {
            Type modelType = Type.GetType(modelTypeValue.FirstValue);
            if (this._binders.TryGetValue(modelType, out var modelBinder))
            {
                ModelBindingContext innerModelBindingContext = DefaultModelBindingContext.CreateBindingContext(
                    bindingContext.ActionContext,
                    bindingContext.ValueProvider,
                    this._metadataProvider.GetMetadataForType(modelType),
                    null,
                    bindingContext.ModelName);

                /*modelBinder*/
                this._binders.First().Value.BindModelAsync(innerModelBindingContext);

                bindingContext.Result = innerModelBindingContext.Result;
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        }

       //More code
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your controller action?

Comment: Updated with the controller code. Please note that I have tried with [ModelBinder(BinderType = ... Name = "Thebase")]. This gives the ModelName but i still cannot generate the derived class in the binder. Just to test I tried forcing to generate the derived class in the binder but all I get in the action method is a instance of the class with properties values not set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the issue. You dont need the provider. Just the following binder works

```
public class BlahTypeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));

        var json = ExtractRequestJson(bindingContext.ActionContext);
        var jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);
        var whatTypeInt = (int)jObject.SelectToken("WhatType");

        if (whatTypeInt == 1)
        {
            var obj = DeserializeObject<A>(json);
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(obj);
        }
        else if (whatTypeInt == 2)
        {
            var obj = DeserializeObject<B>(json);
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(obj);
        }
        else
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private static string ExtractRequestJson(ActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var content = actionContext.HttpContext.Request.Body;
        return new StreamReader(content).ReadToEnd();
    }

    private static T DeserializeObject<T>(string json)
    {
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.Auto
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## The examples you linked to use an external query string parameter to determine the type.

If you **call your action like this**: `SomeAction?WhatType=YourNamespaceName.A` the binding works as expected.

`bindingContext.ModelName` being empty is just fine, it would be set after model binding. You can set it after setting bindingContext.Result if you want. Parameter `WhatType` comes from the `QueryStringValueProvider`, so no prefix is fine.

## How to accomplish abstract model binding based on the JSON alone

To do this, we need:

1. A value provider to read the JSON and provide us with some "WhatType" value, in place of the QueryStringValueProvider.
2. Some reflection to map the extracted numbers to the `Type`-s.

### 1. ValueProvider

There is a detailed article on creating ValueProviders here:

As a starting point here is some code that successfully extracts the WhatType integers from the body json:

```
    public class BlahValueProvider : IValueProvider
{
    private readonly string _requestBody;

    public BlahValueProvider(string requestBody)
    {
        _requestBody = requestBody;
    }

    private const string PROPERTY_NAME = "WhatType";

    public bool ContainsPrefix(string prefix)
    {
        return prefix == PROPERTY_NAME;
    }

    public ValueProviderResult GetValue(string key)
    {
        if (key != PROPERTY_NAME)
            return ValueProviderResult.None;

        // parse json

        try
        {
            var json = JObject.Parse(_requestBody);
            return new ValueProviderResult(json.Value<int>("WhatType").ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO: error handling
            throw;
        }
    }
}

public class BlahValueProviderFactory : IValueProviderFactory
{
    public Task CreateValueProviderAsync(ValueProviderFactoryContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        var request = context.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request;
        if (request.ContentType == "application/json")
        {
            return AddValueProviderAsync(context);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private Task AddValueProviderAsync(ValueProviderFactoryContext context)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(context.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Body))
        {
            string bodyString = sr.ReadToEnd();
            context.ValueProviders.Add(new BlahValueProvider(bodyString));
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Of course **you have to register this factory** in Startup.cs just as you registered the model binder. And this absolutely misses converting the extracted number to the actual Type (for this, see point 2 below), but if you place a breakpoint on your line staring with `if (modelTypeValue != null` you can see that modelTypeValue is there for you now even without the separate GET parameter.

### 2. Reflection

Realize that you are trying to figure out the type based on a property that is dynamically calculated **on an existing instance** (they are not static). While by knowing the current implementation I know that this is possible (create an empty instance of the model, check the `WhatType` property, throw the instance away), this is very bad practice, as nothing guarantees that an instance property is statically constant.

**The clean solution for this would be an Attribute**, that contains the WhatType number for that class. Then we can reflect on that attribute and build a map that maps `int`s to `Type`s. This is out of the scope if this question, but look up any custom attribute tutorial if you are not familiar, and you will be able to put it together really quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your post Marcell. However this does not solve the problem. In my case, even if I force the type - so 
this._metadataProvider.GetMetadataForType(typeof(A)) 
I get an instance of A but all the properties are not set. Please note in my actual case I have other properties in the class. See my comment to Tao above